# Why do Netbeans, Aptana Studio and Komodo Edit all not save in UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, text-editor, netbeans-7, aptana3, komodoedit

I'm getting back into development and want to find a good editor for HTML5/JQuery.

Being able to save files in UTF-8 is important.

However, although I set my project in **NetBeans 7.0** to encode in UTF-8, when I create a file in the project, then look at it in Notepad++, the file is encoded in ANSI and I have to manually set the encoding to UTF-8:

[image]

In **Aptana Studio 3** I set the workspace to UTF-8 encoding, and my project inherits from that, but when I create a file in the project and look at it in Notepad++, it is encoded in ANSI and I have to change the encoding manually to UTF-8:

[image]

So I tried **Komodo Edit 7** and in the file manually set the encoding to UTF-8, saved the file, looked at it in Notepad++ which said the file is in ANSI.

[image]

I notice in any of these editors if I put a German umlaut character in the file, then Notepad++ shows it as "ANSI as UTF-8" but I still have to manually change it to UTF-8 in Notepad++ where it will stay.

The reason I want an editor that saves in UTF-8 is I remember having a project a couple years ago which had German and French characters in the files and after they were viewed and saved in various editors, the characters would be replaced with garbage characters. The solution was to always initially set the encoding of the file to UTF-8.

I assumed that editors would be so far advanced now that if you specify that the files should be saved in UTF-8, that they actually save in UTF-8 in a way that is recognized by every modern text editor. Is this not the case? What am I not understanding about modern text editors and development environments in regard to UTF-8?

**How can I get these editors to save their files in UTF-8 encoding?**

Answer (score 3):

A UTF-8 encoded file that only contains characters also present in the ASCII table (the first 128 Unicode characters, i.e. your basic alphanumeric characters) is indistinguishable from an ASCII/ANSI encoded file. My guess is that Notepad++ simply can't make the distinction (because there is none) and defaults to ANSI. You can see the difference when you include a character that is not in the ASCII table. By "ANSI as UTF-8" I can only guess that it means "this documents contains characters from the ANSI table (a.k.a. Latin-1) and is saved in UTF-8".

In other words, your IDEs are probably fine, the problem is with Notepad++.

Try a character like 漢字, that will result in a pretty unique UTF-8 byte sequence that's most certainly *not* ANSI.

Comment: In Aptana, when I create and save a file with the text "漢字lkdfjsdlfksjdlfksdää", in Notepad++ it shows as "ANSI as UTF-8". When I then open the file in Windows7/Notepad, add "aaa" and save the file, then Notepad shows the file as UTF-8. I thought that text files saved this information in the first three characters or BOM, although I now see that in Aptana there is no way to specify "UTF-8 BOM" but just "UTF-8".

Comment: UTF-8 does not require a BOM. In fact, the BOM is frowned upon in UTF-8 since UTF-8 is deliberately designed to be backwards compatible with ASCII. Maybe that's what "ANSI as UTF-8" means. I know Notepad likes to add a BOM regardless.

Comment: This answer is correct. Notepad++ will attempt to determine the file encoding based on what's in the file when there is no BOM. It's not always right. If you throw some Thai language characters into your file, notepad++ will guess ANSI even if you try to "convert to utf8 without BOM"

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen on this topic, Notepad's UTF-8 equates to Notepad++'s UTF-8, which means with BOM included.  If a file is saved with this encoding and opened in NetBeans, it will actually show a `-` character or the `ï»¿` characters for the BOM sequence (depending on whether the encoding for the project or IDE is set to UTF-8.)  But if you save the file in Notepad++ encoded as "UTF-8 without BOM", and have either your project defined as UTF-8 or have your netbeans_default_options included with this `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, you'll see what I think is UTF-8 as it should be.  Unfortunately, if you try to edit this file in NetBeans without including characters that are outside of the ANSI code set, you see the behavior that you referred to in your question with the file having its encoding set to ANSI.

So in an attempt to make this a "sort-of" answer to your question, please remember that not all editor's concept of UTF-8 are the same.  Notepad++ gives the most actual info on what the real encoding for a file is.  I'd say that developing in either a Linux or Mac environment might be a possible good choice for making sure that localization is correct, but on Windows a decent workaround might be to just include a non-ANSI character in the file to insure it always get saved as a UTF-8 (non-BOM) file.  This is all geared towards NetBeans dev by the way.  I haven't tested this with the others, though I'm willing to bet that they will save the file correctly on a Windows machine if they have non-ANSI characters in them.  Sorry for the kluge gang, but either way, I hope it helps someone struggling with this same issue.