# HTML Charset UFT-8 does not work on every page

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, web

i have created 3 .html files and in every file i did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The structure is in every file the same, the funny thing is that on 2 pages the Charset is working but on 1 page is it not! On the one page i have to remove the Carset else the text on the page is broken.
Does anyone how why this is not working?

Here is the Website: [www.ivr.immo](http://www.ivr.immo)

Comment: 1) Make sure to **actually save your .html files in UTF-8.** 2) You should be setting HTTP headers instead of `<meta>` tags; those are only fallbacks.

Comment: That is absolutly not a duplicate because it is a whole other case but okay.. 
do you know how i can the files in UTF-8? do i need a special programm for that? my netbeans or note++ cant save the files in UTF-8

Comment: How "can't" they save the files in UTF-8? What have you tried, what makes you think they "can't"? Perhaps check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10309088/476

Comment: Ah okay, i have found a site in google and they said that you have to save the UTF-8 encoding under "save as". In netbeans and note++ there was not such an option but now i see that they had a "encoding" option. Thanks you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your meta tag with charset on page http://ivr.immobilien/impressum.html is commented. You can read about html comments [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp)

To fix this, you need to modify your html code.

Comment: i commented it out because else it will break my text on the page

Comment: polest , maybe it's something wrong with this particular text encoding. You can try to replace it with text from another page and ckeck if it works.

Comment: the problem was the file encoding. I changed the file encoding for the impressum.html to UTF-8 and saved it. Now everything is working